# JMeter access bsh.shared in if controller

Tags: jmeter

I want to know if it's possible to access the beanshell shared space in an if controller condition? My variable is bsh.shared.srcList

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Beanshell function.

---

Lets assume I set a variable like this.

`bsh.shared.guru="10";`

In if controller, you can access it using,

`${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.guru)}`

Comment: The example above works for me. The following wont work ${__Javascript(bsh.shared.guru)}